# "If I were.." usage

Tags: grammar, word-usage

"If I were at your place then I wouldn't have done that"

Is the usage of sentence written above fine?

Comment: The more common phrasing in U.S. English omits the word _then_. People become so accustomed to the "if X, then Y" structure of statements like this one that they frequently omit the following _then_ because readers and hearers immediately recognize its implicit presence in the syntactic structure of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's grammatical as written. However, a more common phrasing (for northeast US, anyway) would be "If I were you, I wouldn't have done that."  [Here's an ngram chart of some similar phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+at+your+place%2Cwere+in+your+place%2Cwere+in+your+shoes%2Cif+I+were+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20at%20your%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20in%20your%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20in%20your%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20were%20you%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: "If I were you, I wouldn't have done that." - interesting interpretation (and probably on the money).  I thought it meant "If I were at your house ..." not "If I were in your place ..."! So OP if you mean "If I were you, I wouldn't have done that.", then your sentence is not correct.

Comment: @cargill I didn't mean to this " if I were you, I wouldn't have done that" I know this sentence is incorrect though the correct one would be "if I were you , I wouldn't do that". And I meant "If I were at your place".